# Why can one suppose $\alpha^i$ and $\beta$ matrices in the derivation of the Dirac Equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, dirac-equation

On the derivation of the Dirac Equation one usually supposes that it is possible to write

$$E = \mathbf{\alpha}\cdot \mathbf{p} + \beta m.$$

One then deduces that in order to have $E^2 = p^2+m^2$ it is necessary that:

$$\dfrac{1}{2}(\alpha^i\alpha^j +\alpha^j\alpha^i)=\delta^{ij} \\ \alpha^i \beta + \beta \alpha^i = 0 \\ \beta^2 = I,$$

After that one usually says that "because of that $\alpha^i$ and $\beta$ must be matrices. Now, this is *really* odd, IMHO, for the following reasons:

1. If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are matrices, $E$ is a matrix, but we know that $E$ must be a number.
2. Also, if $\alpha^i$ are matrices, $\alpha$ is a vector of matrices and is not clear to me what $\alpha\cdot \mathbf{p}$ would be.

I don't get this reasoning really. What is behind all of that? Why can we suppose $\alpha^i$ and $\beta$ matrices when $E$ is a number? How to understand and get some intuition behind all of this?

Comment: A lot of times, physicists are lazy and write $E$ as a number, when they mean $E \mathbb I$, where $\mathbb I$ stands for an identity matrix of the appropriate dimension.

Comment: It's not laziness, it's just a natural clever notation. The objects on both sides are operators, and a multiplication by $E1$ is the same as the  multiplication by $E$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) The problem with this is that your first equation should be
$$
H = \mathbf{\alpha}\cdot \mathbf{p} + \beta m
$$
with $H$ the hamiltonian instead of $E$. Now, the energies are the *eigenvalues* of $H$, that is, the eigenvalues of a matrix. As eigenvalues are just numbers everything works out just fine.
\begin{aligned}
H\quad&\quad\text{matrix.}\\
E\quad&\quad\text{the eigenvalue of $H$, that is, a number.}
\end{aligned}

2) $\alpha\cdot \boldsymbol p$ is a shorthand notation for $\alpha_x p_x+\alpha_y p_y+\alpha_z p_z$, that is, the sum of three matrices. The result is a $4\times 4$ matrix, that is, $\alpha\cdot \boldsymbol p$ is a matrix.